# Alternatives to Flexbox and Flex-Direction

Tags: html, email, flexbox

I think this should be a simple question, so I won't be putting code here at this point. My question is this - I have an email that works in all the ways I want, except for one thing. For Gmail on Android (app), display:flex works, but not for any of the other parts that come with it (flex-direction, etc.). I need to reverse two columns in a table and flex was working for me on every other client. So, does anyone have a good alternative that would help me accomplish this goal for the Gmail App on Android?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Set the class "reorder-mobile" on the table element, and rearrange the td's with the following code:

```css
.reorder-mobile tr td {
    display:table-header-group;
   }
 
   .reorder-mobile tr td:first-child {
    display:table-footer-group;
   }
```

This worked for me in Gmail and the Outlook App.